# Ethical dilemma with customers serviced

Tags: ethics

I work as a firmware engineer in the tech industry. My division and team in particular works with client side solutions (v.s. server solutions), but has since moved to Chinese customers. From hiring, however, I was informed what kind of products I would be making and for who.

I am somewhat of a young engineer and have been realizing at my working time that we are supplying parts of the technology the Chinese government needs to suppress minorities. I have no ill-will against Chinese people myself, however, I want to recognize that the Chinese government has committed many recent human rights violations.

I cannot explain exactly how or what I do to support the technology needed, but I can say that I certainly contribute to some problems in China at the moment.

I am conflicted what the best course of action is because this is my second job for only a year, and my previous job was for a little over a year. I fear that moving jobs will look like I am a job hopper with no commitment. To be honest, I truly enjoy the technical sides of this current job, but I am really uncomfortable with my current position, knowing that my company is ok with knowingly supporting mass surveillance.

If I were to apply to another company, I suspect that ethical reasons would not realistically be an excusable reason. What could I do in my position?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> I fear that moving jobs will look like I am a job hopper with no commitment.

I think you're worrying over nothing. It's only your second job, and
your first was just over a year... I can't imagine anyone viewing that as job hopping.

> I suspect that ethical reasons would not realistically be an excusable reason. What could I do in my position?

There is nothing wrong with saying you left due to ethical reasons, that's
a perfectly acceptable, and even admirable reason.

If you're uncomfortable with what your company is doing then start looking for another job.

Comment: I meant to say that some companies might see ethical reasons as a weak excuse. I don’t know if stating that I was not a good culture fit would be a better reason since both reasons are technically valid.

Comment: You can choose either, depending on whether you think the potential employer would be more worried about you addressing *their* ethics or *their* work culture.

Comment: A company that would see ethical reasons as a weak excuse doesn't have any moral principles, and that's what you're trying to get away from. -- You can always include both eg: "The company culture and ethics didn't sit well with me" etc..